# Как отправить данные в поле input через Selenium(python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отправить дату в формате YYYY-MM-DD в поле input через Selenium на Python. Поле input выглядит следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если отправить данные через `driver.find_element_by_xpath('тут путь').send_keys('2021-17-01')`, то возвращается ошибка:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
> element not interactable

Сам элемент страницы - input - он определяется. Проверял выводом `print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('тут путь'))`

Элемент на странице выглядит следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может быть ошибка связана с тем, что я отправляю строку? форма на сайте принимает лишь число

Comment: форма принимает `дд.мм.гггг`, а вы судя по коду отправляете `2021-17-01`

Comment: Пробовал по разному, вплоть то того, что отправлял просто одно число

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> может быть ошибка связана с тем, что я отправляю строку? форма на сайте принимает лишь число

-Нет, метод send_keys в selenium принимает в качестве аргумента строку.

Скорее всего дело в том, что Selenium не видит поле input, и нужно проскроллить до него.
Возможно, ответ на ваш вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйся функцией `is_displayed()` чтобы проверить видимость объекта, но твоя проблема в том, что у тебя поле с маской. Поля с маской невозможно передать через функцию `send_keys()` без передачи перед строкой функции, которую выполняет кнопка HOME на клавиатуре.

Попробуй следующее:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '<твой x_path>').send_keys(Keys.HOME + '2021-17-01')
```

Однако также стоит обратить внимание, что маска у тебя через точку и дата записана в ином формате (последовательности), так что если не сработает описанный выше вариант попробуй вот такой:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '<твой x_path>').send_keys(Keys.HOME + '17.01.2021')
```

Comment: не от gpt ли этот текст?

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Нет, Александр, ответ создан не chat GPT, а мной и является верным в моем случае для сайта gias.by, в котором я столкнулся с такой же проблемой при передаче значения в поле "Код ОКРБ". А ваше кажется отрицательная оценка выглядят как-то прискорбно. Вы бы как минимум должны были проверить верность и полезность решения перед тем как что-то писать и тем более снижать рейтинг ответа. Я сам потратил довольно много времени и решил проблему, вы препятствуете быстрому нахождению решения другими людьми